# Add if-then-else logic to Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps.
I have added an Agentless job running that calls a REST API endpoint.
At the moment this works as expected.
However my next challenge is to take the response from the API call and perform some tasks. Here is a breakdown of the logic I am trying to achieve:

- GET list of students (Connect to REST API with GET)
- Read response from above step and look for a specific value
- If value exists continue
- If value does not exist then POST new value to REST API endpoint

Like I said, I have step 1 sorted but I do not know how to add the if-then-else logic

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the output of your response to get your specific value.

```
$reponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -URI $url
$specificValue = $response.output.specificValue
if(!$specificValue) { 
  ##value does not exist
  Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -URI $url -Body $body
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.